# Returning after ajax call prints false

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Could you please help me to understand why this returns false?
Response.data returns true, I assign it to variable 'valid' but when I return it at the end, it is false.

```
var  valid = false;

factory.validate = function(id)
{

            data ={ 'id' : id };
            $http.post('php/validate.php', data).then
            (
                function(response)
                {
                    valid = response.data;
                    // Prints true here
                    console.log(response.data);
                    console.log(valid);
                },
                function(error)
                {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );

            // Returns and prints false here
            console.log(valid);
            return valid;
        };
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns false because it is asynchronous, and it hasnt received the server response yet from your post request.

If you want to use functions return value to do something once the form has validated/server has responded, then you can use angular's $q

```
this.validate = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); 
    setTimeout(function() {//or do your post request that takes some time
        deferred.resolve();//validate the response etc and resolve as true.
        //or if something went wrong or didnt validate, reject.
        deferred.reject("Your form contained some errors"); 
    },1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

In case of your example, you can simply return the $http.post()'s return value, and use that instead ( $http requests return a promise object ).

```
//your code with minor edits
factory.validate = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data ={ 'id' : id };
    $http.post('php/validate.php', data).success(function(response) {
        if ( response.is_valid ) {deferred.resolve("all OK");}
        else {deferred.reject("Error: your data is invalid");}
    }).error(function() {
        deferred.reject("Error:could not contact the server");
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

//then use the validation code like this
validate(112).then(function() {
    //things validated and all is OK, give user some feedback
    alert("your stuff is valid");
},function(message) {
    alert(message);
});
```